# Create a wxPython app that has only one instance

Tags: wxwidgets, wxpython

I would like to create a wxPython app such that:

- If I run a second instance of that app (e.g., call the Python script from the shell a second time), no new instance should be created.
- Instead, the toplevel frame of the already running instance should be raised and focussed.

The first point can be easily implemented by [wx.SingleInstanceChecker](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.SingleInstanceChecker.html#wx.SingleInstanceChecker.CreateDefault) (see the example code there), but at least the example code only gives a way for making the second instance of the app abort, but not raise the existing app's main frame.

I am using wxPython-Phoenix with Python 3.

**Claritication:** I would much prefer an out-of-the-box solution like wx.SingleInstanceChecker (that is, not implement my own locking and IPC solution).

Answer (score 0):

You can use any kind of IPC to send a message asking the other program to do whatever needs to be done (just raise its top level window or maybe handle the command line options passed to the second instance). In C++ there are [wxConnection](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.1/classwx_connection.html) and the related `wxServer` and `wxClient` classes that can be used for this, but I'm not sure if they're wrapped by wxPython -- however you could use any Python IPC module instead, if they aren't.

Comment: Yes, that would work. But I would prefer not to have to implement this from scratch...

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out, the "correct" way to do this is IPC because you have a new process that is supposed to affect a change (raise and focus) in another process.

What you seem to want is to take advantage of the IPC channel that wx.SingleInstanceChecker is already using to do your work.  Unfortunately, you can't.  That class is implemented in the wxWidgets c++ code and therefore there are no Python bindings to the internal workings of the class.

However, you can probably abuse wx.SingleInstanceChecker to do what you want.  In your program, you can set up a timer at some rapid interval (say, 250ms) that will constantly check `IsAnotherRunning()` from your main process.  Therefore, when your second process starts up, the first will notice and can raise itself to the front.  You would just have to wait for a little bit in the secondary process before it exits, to give the first time to notice.